# Concatenating PDF using PDFsharp returns empty PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, concatenation, pdfsharp

I have a list of PDF stored as `list<byte[]>`. I try to concatenate all these PDF files using PDFsharp, but after my operation I get a PDF with proper page count, but all pages are blank. Looks like I lose some header or something but I can't find where.

My code:

```
        PdfDocument output = new PdfDocument();
        try
        {
            foreach (var report in reports)
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(report))
                {

                    PdfDocument input = PdfReader.Open(stream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

                    foreach (PdfPage page in input.Pages)
                    {
                        output.AddPage(page);
                    }
                }
            }


            if (output.Pages.Count <= 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Empty Document");
            }
            MemoryStream final = new MemoryStream();
            output.Save(final);
            output.Close();
            return final.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.ToString());
        }
```

I want to return it as `byte[]` because I use them later:

`return File(report, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "test.pdf");`

This returns PDF with proper page count, but all blank.

Comment: Does   output.Save(filename); work?

Comment: Do you get a correct file when you save to a file? If not then maybe there is a problem with the PDF files you import. If yes then the problem could be with the MemoryStream you are using (it gets closed twice before you call ToArray - and without Debugger I can't say if that's a problem). Without MCVE I won't try to debug your problem.

Comment: When I just return one of the pdf without using PDFSharp it work proper. When i use PDFSharp to concatenate 6 pdf with one page i get 1 pdf with 6 pages as result but all pages are blank.

Comment: With just a code snippet and without PDF files we cannot investigate this issue properly. Please provide an MCVE.
Do you get six empty pages also when you save to a file?

Comment: Yes I get six empty page but size of file is correct. Also when i check the final `byte[]` it contain information, it look like i losing header. I cannot give you pdf sample because i  generate it in run time from SSRS report. I'm 100 % sure that PDF that i generate are correct because I used it in past.

Comment: SSRS might be the important piece of information. Which version of PDFsharp are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tell in a comment that the files come from SSRS.

Older versions of PDFsharp require a special SSRS setting:

> For the DeviceSettings parameter for the Render method on the ReportExecutionService object, pass this value:

```
theDeviceSettings = "<DeviceInfo><HumanReadablePDF>True</HumanReadablePDF></DeviceInfo>";
```

Source:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=1613#p1613

Comment: Thanks I switch version of PDFSharp form 1.32 to 1.50 Beta_3B and it work now. I belive that if i add this setting and use older version i will work too. Thanks for your help. I didn't expect that the creator of DLL will try to help me. Awesome way to support product :) Thanks again :)

Comment: where i can add this line  as parameter??
theDeviceSettings = "<DeviceInfo><HumanReadablePDF>True</HumanReadablePDF></DeviceInfo>"; 

my code :
var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html,PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);

Comment: @rahman That's an SSRS setting that must be added to the SSRS settings before generating a PDF file with SSRS.

Answer (score -1):

I use iTextSharp, look at this saple code (it works)

```
public static byte[] PdfJoin(List<String> pdfs)
    {
        byte[] mergedPdf = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy copy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(document, ms))
                {
                    document.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < pdfs.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfs[i]);
                        // loop over the pages in that document
                        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                        for (int page = 0; page < n; )
                        {
                            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mergedPdf = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return mergedPdf;
    }




 public static byte[] PdfJoin(List<byte[]> pdfs)
    {
        byte[] mergedPdf = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy copy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(document, ms))
                {
                    document.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < pdfs.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfs[i]);
                        // loop over the pages in that document
                        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                        for (int page = 0; page < n; )
                        {
                            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mergedPdf = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return mergedPdf;
    }
```

Comment: Probably You have right but i can't use iText ( this is company code so i must use PDFSharp )